# AS3: Getting the x & y value of a matched string in a text field

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I have a text field within Flash that contains a block of (obviously) text.

What I want to do is perform a search on the content of the text field that returns the `x & y` coordiante and the `width & height` of the found text. The result will be used to place a visual element over that portion of the text box.

For example:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /\d+/g;
var found:Array = box.text.match(pattern);

var i:String;
for each(i in found)
{
    /**
     * Find the x, y, width, height of the matched text in the text field
     * Use result to place transparent yellow box around text
     */
}
```

Which visually should result in something like:

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, I always wondered how that was done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to make use of the TextField class's `getCharBoundaries` method, which accepts character indexes and returns a Rectangle object.

As far as I know, your `match` method returns the strings themselves, so first you'll probably need to use the String class's `indexOf` method, find all your character indexes, pass them to the `getCharBoundaries` method, then draw some rectangles based on that output.

[Here's some reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#getCharBoundaries%28%29).

Good luck!

Comment: Ah, very nice. I'm using match() to parse regex (to find numbers in this case) and with the matched will use indexOf(). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought I'd have to do word wrap math or something. So glad this exists.